# Diferencias y usos de javax.swing.JList y javax.swing.DefaultListModel

Tags: java, java-swing

He estado haciendo una pequeña aplicación donde estoy utilizando listas y me tope con defaultlistmodel y observando he visto que sólo cambian en la forma de declarar las propiedades.La cuestión es que además de ésta existen otras diferencias en cuanto al uso de cada una, y también como es posible que de una lista de opciones al seleccionar algunas estas se visualicen en otra lista independiente.

Comment: JList es un componente visual que usas para poder mostrar una lista agregándolo en algún JPanel u otro componente visual. Mientras que DefaultListModel es más bien para contener una lista y dar avisos de cambios a otros objetos que la requieran escuchar.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Como menciona el compañero en el comentario, una **JList** es un componente de "peso ligero" (es decir, liviano), que visualmente se muestra y puede ser agregado en algún contenedor (como un **JPanel** o un **JFrame**).  Un **JList** y un **DefaultListModel** son cosas completamente distintas.

Un **JList** es un componente, y un **DefaultListModel** es un modelo que puede ser utilizado en ese componente.

Un modelo es la forma en la que vas a organizar tu lista, además que es el que **almacena** los objetos que agregues (los objetos **NO** se almacenan en el **JList**, ellos se almacenan en el modelo que tenga ese componente).

Ahora, el **JList** trae por defecto un tipo de modelo, y ese modelo es la interfaz **ListModel**, el cuál incluye ciertos métodos diferentes al **DefaultListModel**. ¿Por qué?

Esto se debe a que la interfaz **ListModel**, se utiliza casi *únicamente* para obtener los valores de una **JList**, como se indica en la [documentación de Java para un ListModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html).

Por otro lado, el **DefaultListModel** es más una clase que te permite realizar más acciones (como agregar, obtener, eliminar, ajustar), según se indica en [documentación de Java para un DefaultListModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html).

Además de esto, existen otros tipos de modelos que pueden ser utilizados según lo requieras.

Dicho esto, la forma en la que puedes modificar el modelo de un componente **JList** es por medio del método `JList.setModel(tuModelo);`, donde "tuModelo" es una instancia del modelo que quieras utilizar. Por ejemplo, si quisieras modificar el modelo de tu **JList** (un **ListModel**) por un **DefaultListModel**, simplemente harías algo así:

```
DefaultListModel miModelo = new DefaultListModel(); // se instancia el nuevo modelo
// puedes utilizar el método miModelo.add(miObjeto); para agregar objetos al modelo antes ser ajustado al JList
JList.setModel(miModelo); // ajusta el nuevo modelo a tu JList
```

De esta manera, se cambiará el modelo de tu **JList**.